# ontextchanged event in java

Tags: java, swing

i am looking al events in java http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html

i want ontextchanged event like in C# that when text changed event is executed.
Which event is the right one in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should say which Swing widget you're looking at,a s behaviour is quite different. But, to make long things short, here is a primer.

Most of text widgets use, internally, a model which is a [`Document`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html). This Document is updated by the widget and sends, in turn, Document events. So, to listen text change whichever widget you use, you can create a [`DocumentListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

I also suggest you take a look at some lessons of the Swing tutorial :

- [How to Use Text Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)